# PHP how to combine two arrays a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3?

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have two arrays like this:

```
$one = array('a', 'b');
$two = array('1', '2', '3');
```

I need output this :

```
array( 
'a' => '1',
'a' => '2',
'a' => '3',
'b' => '1',
'b' => '2',
'b' => '3'
);
```

Any solution?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys

Comment: There is no solution to that. That is an array that can't be made since you use the same keys multiple times

Comment: do you have a solution ?

Comment: @alifiaavirista, you can use the [array.merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) method, but as others have commented, you need to have unique keys.

Comment: you can make like this `array('a1'=>1,'a2'=>2,'a3'=>3.....).;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to get this:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

You get that from looping the two arrays nested and create a new array in the loop.

```
$one = array('a', 'b');
$two = array('1', '2', '3');

$result = array();
foreach($one as $elem) {
    $result[$elem] = $two;
}


var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/N73KP

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, we are not merging here but creating a new `array $data` which will have mapping of keys from `array $one` and values from `array $two`

```
$one = array('a', 'b');
$two = array('1', '2', '3');

$data = array();
foreach($one as $key) {
    $data[$key] = $two;
}

print_r($data);
```